Can not enable Show in GAL for user sync from AD on Prem to Azure AD
One of our users isn't showing up in GAL.
In M365 admincenter and in Exchange admin center settings are set to hide him from GAL.
Changing in those admincenters is not possible.


In PowerShell I found a property -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled which is set to $True
Can't change it with PowerShell
Can't find it in Attribute Editor of this profile
Even with 'Advanced Features' and Exchange Extended Properties
-- Powershell cmd I tried
Set-Mailbox -Identity "UPN" -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $false
Set-ADUser -identity "UPN" -Replace @{msExchHideFromAddressLists=$true}
